# Create an array with associative array keys and numeric array values PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to combine two arrays. An associative one and a numeric array. `$new_array = array_combine($array1, $array2)`. But it is taking the values from array one and setting them as the keys for the new array, which is what is meant meant to do.

But I need to use the keys of $array1 to be the keys of $new_array and the values of the $array2 to be the values of the $new_array. I also looked into merging the values of $array2 to $array1 but it does not work properly as the arrays don't share the same keys.

Here is an example.

```
$array1 = "fname" => "NULL", "lname" => "NULL", "id" => "NULL";

$array2 = "john", "smith", "11123";

$new_array = "fname" => "john" , "lname" => "smith", id => "11123";
```

I was thinking of using this `array_combine(array_flip($array1), $array2);`

But array_flip can't work with NULL;

Comment: `array_flip()` wouldn't give you the right result, perhaps you're  looking for `array_keys()`

Comment: *I am looking for other options* - some mystery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) instead of [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) like so:

```
$array1 = ["fname" => "NULL", "lname" => "NULL", "id" => "NULL"];

$array2 = ["john", "smith", "11123"];

$new_array = array_combine(array_keys($array1), $array2);

print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [fname] => john
    [lname] => smith
    [id] => 11123
)
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/882792)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate and assign

```
  $i = 0;
  foreach( $array1 as $key=>$value){
    $new_array[$key]=> $array2[$i];
    $i++;
  }
```