# How can i do merge arrays by my specific situation

Tags: php, arrays

I have to arrays, these:

```
    $array1 = [
        'red' => 'pencil',
        'blue' => 'eraser',
    ];

    $array2 = [
        'reding' => '',
        'bluing' => '',
    ];
```

and i wanna get this output:

```
    $output = [
        'reding' => 'pencil',
        'bluing' => 'eraser',
    ];
```

So, values come from `$array1` and keys come from `$array2` on the `$output`.

Note: elements in array count is variable.

How can i do this ? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: `array_combine(array_keys($array2), $array1);` if arrays are always the same length

Comment: thank you, why not you don't write this code as response ?

Comment: have written :)

Comment: The relationship is unclear.  Are the elements combined by offset or key similarity?  This is surely a duplicate question if associated by offset.  Downvoted because unclear, no reasearch, no attempt.

Comment: EXACT duplicate of [Create an array with associative array keys and numeric array values PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833721/create-an-array-with-associative-array-keys-and-numeric-array-values-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if arrays are always the same length

```
array_combine(array_keys($array2), $array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

Creates an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the values from the values array as the corresponding values.

More Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)